# How can I access to DDEV project from Virtualbox guest?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ddev

I have used DDEV for some time now and it is currently the best solution for running Drupal sites on my local environment. I run into one problem - sometimes you need to test site with Internet Explorer or Edge and I can do it only with Virtualbox, but how can I access to my project inside Virtualbox? I know there is ngrok integration available but it is not that comfortable.

Can anyone more familiar with DDEV help out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ddev share` and you can test with browsers from anywhere, including Virtualbox. I think you'll like it. See `ddev help share`. There's a nice article on it at https://www.drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2019/06/sharing-your-ddev-local-site-public-url-using-ddev-share-and-ngrok